# stuck with nodejs callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
getDbFiles(store, function(files){
require('ms-db').connect("DBname", function (db) {
    db.collection('collectionName').find().toArray(function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
        store = data;
    })
});
      getCdnFiles(store, function(files1) {

      });});
```

I want to call this getDbFiles func make query, whose result should be accessible by getCdnFiles(), but it is showing error that 'store ' is not defined. so pls help me with this, how to achieve this using node js and callbacks...

Comment: Ideed, `store` is not defined. Is that your whole code?

Comment: no that is not the whole code, I have no idea how to achieve this..

Comment: You have to put `getCdnFiles` inside the callback that creates `store` so that `store` exists at the time.

Comment: it also shows that geDbFiles() is not defined..

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result of `getDbFiles` to be accessible by `getCdnFiles` you need to move the call to `getCdnFiles` into the callback function of `db.collection`

```
getDbFiles(store, function(files){
  require('ms-db').connect("DBname", function (db) {
    db.collection('collectionName').find().toArray(function (err, data) {
      console.log(data);
      store = data;

      getCdnFiles(store, function(files1) {

      });
    });
  });
});
```

You can also use [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) to help minimize the callback levels.

Comment: I just barely put together an example for turning *callback hell* into organized code with `async.waterfall`. Thought it might be relevant here so [here it is](https://gist.github.com/Chevex/7299157).